# Union two SELECT queries in one

Tags: mysql, sql

as i can't brain this out I'm asking for your help. I'm not so familiar with UNIONS. I have two SELECT queries which i would like to merge in one. 
So i want to select the name based on userId from table Teams and their gameAcc from table connections based on teamsId.

[image]

I've made two separate queries:

```
SELECT users.name 
FROM users 
JOIN teams 
  ON users.id = teams.usersId 
WHERE teams.Id = 1

SELECT connections.gameAcc 
FROM connections 
JOIN users 
  ON connections.usersId = users.id 
JOIN teams 
  ON connections.teamsId = teams.id 
WHERE teams.id = 1
```

Expected: A single query that will output 1 row with users name from teams table and their gameAcc from connections table. 
Example data:

[image]

And i want it to output:

```
|John| | JohnKiller |
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `UNION ALL`? `SELECT ... UNION ALL SELECT...`

Comment: You don't need a union, you just need to change the select in your second query to `SELECT users.name, connections.gameAcc`. Everything else is there. In fact, you don't even need the join to the teams table. You can change the where clause to `WHERE connections.teamId = 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
From the comments above, you seem to want the name of the owner, and the gameAcc.
In my example below, I changed teams.usersId to "ownerId", to avoid confusion.
I'm assuming that the connections table is joined to the users table, and also to the teams table.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_sql_online.php

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

/* Create tables for example: */
CREATE TABLE USERS(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Name text);
CREATE TABLE TEAMS(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Name text, ownerId integer);
CREATE TABLE CONNECTIONS(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, usersId integer, teamsId integer, gameAcc text);

/* Create new records in these tables */
INSERT INTO USERS VALUES(1,'Jim');
INSERT INTO USERS VALUES(2,'Paul');
INSERT INTO USERS VALUES(3,'Tony');
INSERT INTO USERS VALUES(4,'Bill');
INSERT INTO USERS VALUES(5,'Art');
INSERT INTO TEAMS VALUES(11,'Tigers', 1); -- owner = user.id = 1
INSERT INTO TEAMS VALUES(22,'Raptors', 2); -- owner = user.id = 2
INSERT INTO CONNECTIONS VALUES(111, 1, 11, 'gameAcc1');
INSERT INTO CONNECTIONS VALUES(222, 2, 22, 'gameAcc2');
INSERT INTO CONNECTIONS VALUES(333, 3, 22, 'gameAcc2');
INSERT INTO CONNECTIONS VALUES(444, 4, 22, 'gameAcc2');
INSERT INTO CONNECTIONS VALUES(555, 5, 11, 'gameAcc2');
COMMIT;

/* Display desired records from the tables */
SELECT users.name, connections.gameAcc 
FROM users
JOIN connections ON connections.usersId = users.id
JOIN teams ON connections.teamsId = teams.id
WHERE teams.id = 11 AND teams.ownerId = users.id
```

Comment: I have to change my answer based on new OP info. Team contain the owner. Connection contains everyone related to the team. So have to filter to get only owner account

Comment: That's the brilliant and working query! <3 Thanks a lot and once more sorry for the confusion from the beginning. Next time i will explain a lot better.

Answer (score 3):

You need to join the 3 tables and not UNION:

```
SELECT users.name, connections.gameAcc 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN teams ON users.id = teams.usersId 
INNER JOIN connections ON connections.teamsId = teams.id
WHERE teams.Id = 1
```

I used `INNER` joins just like your code. 
Depending on the case maybe you need `LEFT` joins if there is no `WHERE` clause.
Edit, after the questions updates.

```
SELECT u.name, c.gameAcc 
FROM connections c
JOIN users u ON c.usersId = u.id 
JOIN teams t1 ON c.teamsId = t1.id 
JOIN teams t2 ON u.id = t2.usersId 
WHERE t2.id = 1;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198909/discussion-on-answer-by-forpas-union-two-select-queries-in-one).

Answer (score 0):

Split it on steps.

First you want to know the owner

```
  SELECT t.userid
  FROM teams t
  WHERE t.teamid = 1
```

Now you want the owner name

```
  SELECT t.userid, u.name
  FROM teams t
  JOIN users u 
    ON t.userid = u.id
  WHERE t.teamid = 1
```

Now you want the game acc for the owner

```
  SELECT t.userid, u.name, c.gameAcc
  FROM teams t
  JOIN users u 
    ON t.userid = u.id
  JOIN connection c
    ON t.userid = c.userid
  WHERE t.teamid = 1
```

Comment: That's what i want but it somehow outputs this: http://prntscr.com/p0tjiq

Comment: either you did the wrong query or have some error on the data. did you try every step?

Comment: Yes, the first two queries works just perfectly! But once the third table starts messing around too then the query isn't working.

Comment: Again check your data. I create a sample demo and work fine http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/931ad1/2

Comment: You are Joining by teamid, my query join by userid